# Is Wikipedia wrong about reentrancy?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, reentrancy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing) (as of Dec 9, 2016) states that the following code is reentrant, despite modifying a global variable, because `swap` leaves it unchanged:

```
int t;

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int s;

    s = t; // save global variable
    t = *x;
    *x = *y;

    // hardware interrupt might invoke isr() here!
    *y = t;
    t = s; // restore global variable
}
```

However, what if `swap` is interrupted in any other number of places? Is this function reentrant, according to the definition of the term?

*By the way, this article is cited as a source elsewhere on SO -- perhaps someone should improve it.*

Comment: That's bogus IMO.

Comment: If Interrupted, any code can leave data in inconsistent state. In any case, the example is a thread *unsafe* swap.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler at least 3 people thought this article was bogus, but I don't get an attaboy for calling it out?

Comment: The wiki article is messed up. It is unclear why a global is used as a transient variable when the local variable could serve just as well. No global data required. I advise you look elsewhere for information on reentrancy.

Comment: Attaboy!   I'm in transit, hence the previous terse comment.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri it's for demo purposes. "why" isn't part of the question.

Comment: Multi-core processors are ubiquitous today, so the ISR does not necessarily interrupt the other code executing this swap().  Still, assuming a machine that doesn't use supervisory mode to handle interrupts and still supports multiple cores does take a fair stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question it's necessary to observe that "reentrant" is an overloaded term with several accepted meanings, some of them ranging from "stretch" to "blatantly incorrect".

I would say the function is synchronously (but not asynchronously) reentrant, and certainly not thread-safe. That's rather vacuous here since it doesn't call any other functions, but it would be meaningful if it called a callback function which could then call back into this function.

If there were proper use of `volatile` types, the function could plausibly be asynchronously reentrant (but still not thread-safe).

Comment: `volatile` does not guarantee atomicity, which would be required here. In the generalised form of "thread-safe" (i.e. true concurrency, no memory-coherency protocol), `volatile` is too weak a guarantee (and bad advice here) and even `stdatomic.h` alone might be insufficient (it can be used as building-blocks for more complex constructs, e.g. mutexes and semaphores).

Comment: @Olaf: `volatile sig_atomic_t` would, as would implementation-defined specifics of `volatile` in more generality. But that's why I said "could plausibly be", not "is".

Comment: 1) You did not specifically mention `sig_atomic_t`, but `volatile` in general. 2) `sig_atomic_t` is the predecessor of `stdatomic` types and is allowed to use implementation-specific additions to guarantee atomicity. That's not a matter of `voliatile`, though, but this specific type. 3) The `volatile` qualtifer alone for other types is plausibly **not** safe. It particularily does not guarantee asynchronous reentrancy (which implies thread-safety), simply because it does not guarantee atomicity. This is not even guaranteed for most single-CPU systems.

Comment: Asynchronous reentrancy does not imply thread-safety. On a system (e.g. POSIX-conforming) with the ability to block signals, it's trivial to achieve asynchronous reentrancy of a function by blocking signals around critical sections that would otherwise not be reentrant. The same works on bare-metal by masking interrupts. This does nothing to achieve thread-safety.

Comment: FWIW, the article provides its own definition of "reentrant"

Comment: @MaxB: Yes, one that's roughly what I'd call "asynchronously reentrant".

Comment: The code above does not block anything. Even with `volatile`, it only works if the access to `t` is atomic. That is not guaranteed (and on e.g. 8 bit CPUs it typically is not). That's exactly what the standard provides with _Atomic` and the declarations/macros in `stdatomic.h`. `volatile` only guarantees the access itself will not be optimised-out.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm not sure if I'm not being clear or if you keep missing the point intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

You are aware that this `swap()` function is written in a deliberately bogus way.  Even for the purpose of illustrating the concept, it would be better to make `t` a local variable with `static` storage class. This way, we could assume that `t` is not modified elsewhere.

At first sight, the function could be called from an interrupt service routine even if the interruption occurred during the execution because, as they mention, `swap` restores the value of its private global (useless) state upon exit. To this regard, it can be considered reentrant (*asynchronous reentrancy*).

For more complicated functions, that call back user supplied code, whether such callbacks can in turn call the function is also a criteria for reentrancy (*synchronous reentrancy*), but it does not apply here as `swap()` does not call anything.

The problem is hardware has become quite tricky nowadays, and unless you are programming to a simple embedded processor, fiddling with global variables from interrupt routines can have surprising side effects.  `t` should be made `volatile` to prevent some of these, but not all.

On a side note, if `swap()` were to be called by different preemptive threads, the calls and return sequences could be interleaved, a situation that is not handled by the function, not to mention that accesses to the global variable `t` are not guaranteed to be atomic... `swap` is definitely not thread safe.

Comment: Your answer doesn't even mention "reentr". I don't think the function's thread-safety is really in dispute.

Comment: @MaxB: I rephrased my answer to underscore the reentrancy aspects and left the mutithread problem as a side note.  These issues are commonly confused by many programmers, putting them in contrast can be useful.